# How To Scroll a Sub Menu in a Main Facebook Page Using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

I want to scroll inside my chat list in Messenger web, but I can't get it to work. Here's my code:

```py
chatList = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'//div[@class="x1n2onr6"]')

for chat in chatList:
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", chat)
```

I've tried various things, such as:

- `driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight",list)`
- `EventFiringWebDriver` using `css selector`
- To use all the div class names to locate them by XPATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I believe is happening here is there are no new values to scroll into view. When you run the for loop on the chatlist it will run only on the elements found in the first instance.

in order to get around this you will have to run a for loop within a while loop.

first you will have to make sure that the chatlist is the area containing the child elements which contain the text.

```
from time import sleep

recheck_limit = 3

while True:
    
    try:
        # Search through a scroll wrapper and get descendants

        chatList = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,'
             [GET THE SCROLL AREA]/descendant:://div[@class="x1n2onr6"]')

    except NoSuchElementException:
        break

    try:
        # check if chatlist has repeated and break loop if it has.

        if last_set == chatList: 
            recheck_limit -= 1
            sleep(0.5)
            continue
            
            if recheck_limit == 0:
                break

    except UnboundLocalError as em:
        pass

    for chat in chatList:

        print(chat)

        try:
            driver.implicitly_wait(5)

            chat = driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", chat)
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            pass

    # save chatlist to last_set variable (to check if repeated.)

    last_set = chatList
```

This has worked for me in the past.

Comment: This worked but is there a way for it to keep on scrolling until a certain condition is met ,  I don't know if it's crashing but it seems to scrolls for only 2 pages. Thank you very much, I've been trying since morning

Comment: What exception are you getting when it crashes. you can add implicit wait I will edit the code a little.

Comment: No error it justs stops after a certain number of chats.  I'd like it to scroll to the bottom and keep loading more.

Comment: if you're not getting any exceptions. its possible that the elements aren't loading quick  enough. this will result in the same element being scrapped and the  (if last_set == chatList: break) statement being ran.

Comment: The other option is to find a element which is guaranteed to be at the end of the chat list and once selenium sees that element break the loop.

Comment: I'll keep trying thanks alot , using descendants instead of '.find_element()' is really helping me get almost anything from a site